# Exception 0xC0000005 thrown by a basic C++ SDL program when run from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Using SDL 2.0.14 I wrote a basic main function creating an empty window and closing it upon a SDL_QUIT event. When run from the Visual Studio 2019 IDE I am using (x64 platform, both Debug and Release modes), the program works fine up to the point when the window is closed; then the IDE generates the following message:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFBFAE55BB6 (ntdll.dll) in my_program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFBEA2000F.
```

It also points to the code in the exe_common.inl file.
The compiled executable runs without any visible problems though.

The single source file of my program contains the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* args[]){
    const int window_width{ 800 };
    const int window_height{ 600 };
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        std::cout << "SDL init failed" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "My Program",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        window_width,
        window_height,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    if (!window) {
        SDL_Quit();
        std::cout << "Could not create window: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 2;
    }

    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (!quit) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

[screenshot of my Call Stack window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7mO6.png)

Comment: *It also points to the code in the exe_common.inl* -- Inspect the call stack.  The call stack will tell you the sequence of calls that led up to the error.  The `exe_common.inl` is where the code finally breaks down, but not where that breakage originates.

Comment: Here is the screenshot of my Call Stack window at the point where exception message was generated https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7mO6.png

Comment: What is `MultiKyb64.dll" (that is what shows up in the call stack)?  That is where you should start investigating, as that is where the sequence of calls passes through.

Comment: that dll seems to be from something called "MultiKey" you might want to try and uninstall that, to make sure that it's not the thing causing the crash

Comment: @PeterT, indeed, I do use this little MultiKey program for my other work. I did not even have to uninstall it, just exiting it was enough to get rid of the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie your suggestion proved to be very helpful. I am relieved that I did not mess up anything with the library itself at the very first step. Thank you! The question is basically answered.

Comment: (I know that thanks should be expressed with upvotes, but I cannot upvote the comments; if you could instruct a SO newbie how else I can recognize your help, I would be most happy to do it).

Comment: @raw_stick -- MultiKey seems to be a program that hooks into any running program. 
 Anti-viruses and programs that monitor other program usage do the same thing.  For example, programs that monitor whether a user has enough user rights to run a program do this sort of thing.